# Square for $x^2$, Cube for $x^3$, Quartic for $x^4$, and what's for $x^1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

What's the general form for $x^y$?
What's the specialized form for $x^1$ and $x^0$?

Comment: $x^0$ is "unity" or "one". :)

Comment: On a less frivolous note, the $x$ term (variable raised to the first power) in a polynomial is usually called the *linear* term. One can also speak of *quintic* ($x^5$), *sextic* ($x^6$), *septic* ($x^7$)... terms.

Comment: In that context, $x^0$ (times some coefficient) would be called the *constant* term.

Comment: Also, $x^2$ is often referred to as the "quadratic" term rather than the so-called "square" term, especially in the context of polynomials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As J.M. and Rahul Narain pointed out in comments, $x^1$ is often referred to as "linear" and $x^0$ as "constant."  Commonly, though certainly not universally, $x^y$ is a/the "power" with $x$ as the base and $y$ as the exponent.

Answer (score 6):

$x$ used to be called *latus* (latin for *side*---of a square, a cube)

If you are interested in this, you *must* read Cajori's *History of mathematical notations*, which has a thorough discussion of the history of the notation and nomenclature of powers.