# Types of polynomial functions. Quadratic, cubic, quartic, quintic, ...,?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, terminology

I would very much like to have a complete list of the types of polynomial functions. I know that:

\begin{align*}
\text{Quadratic}: \qquad & ax^2+bx+c\\
\text{Cubic}: \qquad & ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\\
\text{Quartic}: \qquad & ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e\\
\text{Quintic}: \qquad & ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f
\end{align*}

What are the names of polynomial functions to the further powers? Sexstic? Septic? Octic? I'm not sure, so if someone could enlighten me, then that would be great. Please provide a list that goes at least to the seventh power, but it would be nice if you could go further. Thanks.

Comment: I think after quintic it becomes cumbersome to name them (since the prefixes become increasingly more complex). Thus, I feel like "degree seven" or "seventh degree" polynomial is more appropriate. If you are really interested in the prefixes look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_prefix there under "ordinal"

Comment: @Alex: You could write this as an answer so it can be accepted and the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: Joiki, thank you for the advice. I will do that.

Comment: There’s something just a little ... unsavory ... about the expression *septic equation*.

Comment: @Brian: By all means, don't try to eat a polynomial.

Comment: [Quite related...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15899)

Comment: Polynomials have the interesting property that mathematicians need to be able to count beyond three to discuss some interesting properties they have. Imagine asking a similar question about 5-dimensional hyperplanes.

Comment: See the link below It explains the different Degrees http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While they do start getting awkward quickly, the next few ordinals are fairly well-defined, largely because of their occasional usage in solving cubic and quartic equations and in defining algebraic curves and surfaces: the [Sextic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SexticCurve.html), the [Septic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septic_equation), and the [Octic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EndrassOctic.html).  Beyond that, they just don't show up often enough to be worth explicitly naming.

Comment: Strange... looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_prefix under the "ordinal" column, it seems that the classically correct forms are actually **septimic** and **octavic**. (The WP link to [septic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septic_equation) does mention *heptimic* and *septimic*...)

Comment: Those may be hypothetically correct, but I can safely say that I've never heard either of those - and have heard 'septic' and 'octic' repeatedly (not regularly, but often enough for them to stick in my head), and obviously (judging from Mathworld/etc) I'm not the only one.  I like the sound of 'octavic', I have to admit, but it brings to mind music much more than mathemtics...

Comment: I agree. Searching for "octavic" brings up [this book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=1Bmjde9vhLIC&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=octavic) ("the inscribed quartics hvae eight nodes on the octavic curve...") first published 1905, a paper from 1881, one from 1933, etc... all from an age when people were more likely to have been classically educated. :-) On Google Scholar, [octavic](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=octavic) has 280 results and [octic](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=octic) 2060; [sextic septimic](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=sextic+septimic) 74 and [sextic septic] 241.

Comment: Now looking back, I do recal a vague memory of it saying septimic in my Algebra book.

Comment: There's a list on Wikipedia pretty much reiterating what's been said here (along with mentioning the "proposed, but...rarely used" names **nonic** and **decic** for degrees 9 and 10.)
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial)

Answer (score 5):

I think after quintic it becomes cumbersome to name them (since the prefixes become increasingly more complex). Thus, I feel like "degree seven" or "seventh degree" polynomial is more appropriate. If you are really interested in the prefixes look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_prefix) under "ordinal".