# What is the proper adjective/adverb for a power function?

Tags: terminology, power-series, exponential-function

I have a function where space grows as a power of time: $x= at^2$.  In my report, I've been using the adjective 'exponential' or adverb 'exponentially' to describe the expansion with time.  However, looking at the textbook definition, it appears that an 'exponential' expansion would look like $x = 2a^t$.  If 'exponential' isn't appropriate, then what is the proper adjective/adverb for my expansion?

Comment: polynomial with order 2? Quadratic growth?

Comment: In this specific case “quadratic” would be appropriate.

Comment: Yup, quadratic would be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The growth of $x^n$ is called linear ($n=1$), quadratic ($n=2$), cubic ($n=3$), quartic ($n=4$), quintic ($n=5$)... You can [find here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76533/10014) a few names after that, but I don't expect anyone to say "octavic/octic" with a straight face. In general if you don't know $n$ it's just called "polynomial growth".

Answer (score 0):

For exponent $2$, you say *quadratic*, for $3$ and following, *cubic*, *quartic*, *quintic*... For general exponent, power function or power law.

[In French you can use *potentielle*, but this can cause polysemic ambiguities.]

The adverb *quadratically* can be freely used; I would abstain from "cubicly", "quarticly"...

Also avoid the confusion with *quadric*, which describes a quadratic surface in 3D space.