# Type of polynomial where leading coefficient is to the power of $6$

Tags: polynomials

I need to identify the type of polynomial that a polynomial is based on the power of the leading coefficient. (Example $x^2$ = quadratic, $x^3$ = cubic, $x^4$ quartic). In this case, it is $x^6$. What is the name of the type for $x^6$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76533/types-of-polynomial-functions-quadratic-cubic-quartic-quintic

Answer (score 1):

Both sextic and hexic are valid names for polynomials of degree $6$.

Comment: Sextic is the name in common use.  I don't think I've ever seen "hexic" used for a polynomial.

Comment: Yeah, I have to agree, I've seen "sextic" many times and I've never seen "hexic."

Answer (score 0):

It's called a "sextic polynomial."

In addition, you can call it a "degree-six polynomial," or a "polynomial of degree six."

Comment: By the way, there's a number called _Conway's constant_, that happens to be the root of a polynomial of _degree 71_. More information on that can be found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence). I think Ian Stewart called it the strangest polynomial he had ever seen in his life.